# Why the state is not updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a state using react hook `useState()` at **line 28** which is `const [input, setInput] = useState('');`. Then I updated the state by calling the `setInput()` at **line 45** in the `createTodo` function at **line 32**. But when the function is executing, the state is not updating. There is no error on the console. I also added a `console.log()` after the state updating statement and the `console.log()` also executing but state is not updating.

My codes are given below.

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AiOutlinePlus } from 'react-icons/ai';
import ToDo from './ToDo';
import { db } from './firebase';
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  onSnapshot,
  query,
  updateDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore';

const style = {
  bg: `h-screen w-screen p-4 bg-gradient-to-r from-[#2F80ED] to-[#1CB5E0]`,
  container: `bg-slate-100 max-w-[500px] w-full m-auto rounded-md shadow-xl p-4`,
  heading: `text-3xl font-bold text-center text-gray-800 p-2`,
  form: `flex justify-between`,
  input: `border p-2 w-full text-xl`,
  button: `border p-4 ml-2 bg-purple-500 text-slate-100`,
  count: `text-center p-2`,
};

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const [input, setInput] = useState('');  // this is the state

  // ************ firebase operations ************
  // create
  const createTodo = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (input === '') {
      alert('Please add some text');
      return;
    }

    // crating data to firebase
    await addDoc(collection(db, 'todos'), {
      text: input,
      completed: false,
    });

    setInput(''); // here state is not updating
  };

  // read
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'todos'));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, querySnapshot => {
      let todosArr = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        todosArr.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      setTodos(todosArr);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  // update
  const toggleComplete = async todo => {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, 'todos', todo.id), {
      completed: !todo.completed,
    });
  };

  // delete
  const todoDelete = async id => {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'todos', id));
  };

  return (
    <div className={style.bg}>
      <div className={style.container}>
        <h2 className={style.heading}>ToDo CRUD with Firebase</h2>
        <form onSubmit={createTodo} className={style.form}>
          <input
            type="text"
            className={style.input}
            placeholder="ToDo"
            onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)}
          />
          <button className={style.button}>
            <AiOutlinePlus size={30} />
          </button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          {todos.map((todo, index) => (
            <ToDo
              key={index}
              todo={todo}
              toggleComplete={toggleComplete}
              todoDelete={todoDelete}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
        {todos.length === 0 ? null : (
          <p className={style.count}>{`You have ${todos.length} todos`}</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Please have a look. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: And how do you know it's not updating?

Comment: state is working, add `value={input}` prop to your input, to see

Comment: The input box is not clearing. I mean the value of input box is not setting to an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `value={input}` in your input element

```
   <input
       type="text"
       className={style.input}
       placeholder="ToDo"
       value={input}    <-- this
       onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)}
    />
```

Comment: Anything wrong with the answer?

Comment: Thank yo so much. You solved my problem. This was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
  type="text"
  className={style.input}
  placeholder="ToDo"
  **value={input}**
  onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)}
/>
```

[https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#:~:text=An%20input%20form%20element%20whose,called%20a%20%E2%80%9Ccontrolled%20component%E2%80%9D.&text=Since%20the%20value%20attribute%20is,state%20the%20source%20of%20truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#:%7E:text=An%20input%20form%20element%20whose,called%20a%20%E2%80%9Ccontrolled%20component%E2%80%9D.&text=Since%20the%20value%20attribute%20is,state%20the%20source%20of%20truth).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).